# My htaccess with cakephp doensn't work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I got a problem with probably my `.htaccess`

I use the cakephp framework (2.0) and i use `.htacces` to redirect a `non-www` to a `www` 
 Using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is now, when somebody clicks on the link http://mysite.nl/controller/view/E1 
They go to http://www.mysite.nl/index.php 
 
instead of http://www.mysite.nl/controller/view/E1 **(with www)**

And this while the rewrite works on **mysite.nl** to **www.mysite.nl**

Can somebody tell me what i do wrong? i have searched for different kind of rewrite rules but with no luck.

Full .htaccess file after comment:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]    
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you make this rule as **first rule** in your main .htaccess.

Comment: Got it now like this (check update)

Comment: With this change can you test in a new browser?

Comment: Strange, when i do it in internet explorer it works, so what you mean is, i need to clean my cache on chrome so i can see that it works?

Comment: Yes clearing the cache will make chrome work.

Comment: Oh perfect, I am going to post this as answer and you can accept to help some future visitor facing similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordering of rules is very important in .htaccess. In general your 301s should appear **before** front controller rules that catch all the requests and change the request URI.

Try this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # add www rule
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    # cakephp front controller rule
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]    
</IfModule>
```